# OpenSSL 1.1.1 RPM for CentOS 7

Tags: openssl, rpm

I'd like an RPM package of OpenSSL 1.1.1 for CentOS 7.
(NOT 1.1.0...)

I've googled around for this very specific RPM file, but it is simply not available.

I've also mailed the `openssl-users`, but no one replied with a correct answer.

--- EDIT ---

Finally, the package is available.

Comment: `1.1.1` has not been packaged yet. Why not make your own package from the source, or install from source ?

Comment: You may be in for a long wait unless you engage someone directly - I'm not sure of the CentOS roadmap and since they follow RHEL it may be worth keeping an eye on release 8 when it comes along.

Comment: Meanwhile, the openssl11 RPM package is available in EPEL 7, providing the same OpenSSL version like in RHEL/CentOS 8.